# Check duplicated value from temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have a source table:

```
ID  Value
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

And a temp table #ABCD:

```
ID  Value
1   b
2   a
3   d
```

I want to update the original table from temp table based on Id match:

```
Original table:
ID  Value
1   b
2   a
3   d (duplicate)
4   d
```

So now my original table has a duplicate value (d)

So how to get the duplicate value (d) from temp table #ABCD? Before updating.
Query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Original](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Original]
           ([Id]
           ,[Value])
VALUES
    (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')
GO
CREATE TABLE #ABCD([Id] INT, [Value] nchar(10))
GO
INSERT INTO #ABCD([Id], [Value]) VALUES (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'd')
```

Result:

```
Duplicated value:
ID Value
3  d
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: "*I want to update the original table ... So how to get the duplicate value ... ?*" - Decide what you want to do. Do you need an update or a select statement?

Comment: I have to find the duplicate values first.

Comment: You have simplified this situation so much that it doesn't make sense. How is "d" a duplicate and not the other letters?

Comment: Do you want the duplicates or the items that aren't duplicates? Duplicate across ID value pair or just across value? The desired output doesn't make any sense compared to the sample tables you've provided.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question. I want to update the original table from the temp table based on Id match. But now I have a duplicated value (d). So how to get the duplicated value (3 d) from temp table first before updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Maybe this is better:

```
select q2.* from (
    select * from #ABCD 
    union 
    select * from original where id not in(select id from #ABCD)
    )q1
    inner join #ABCD  q2 
    on q1.Value = q2.Value 
    and q1.id<>q2.id
```

Try this. I did the update in another temp table and evaluate the final result.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TMP

select * into #TMP 
from original

update t1
    set t1.Value = t2.value
from #TMP t1 
    inner join #ABCD t2 
        on t1.id=t2.id


select a.* from #TMP t1 
inner join #ABCD  t2 
    on t1.Value=t2.Value 
    and t1.id<>t2.id
```